# Como fazer um input mask simulando dinheiro com ionic 2?

Tags: ionic, angular, ionic2

Creio que a pergunta ja está bem explicativa, mas gostaria de saber como posso criar uma `mask` utilizando números decimais para simular as casas da moeda real ( `1.000,00`).

Answer (score 0):

Para a quantidade de casas decimais, você pode usar no `html` o próprio filtro do [angular](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe):

```
{{ value_expression | number [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] }}
```

No seu exemplo, você poderia usar:

```
{{ 1000 | number : '.2' }}
```

Para que o formato do número seja "." para separação de milhares e "," para separar as casas decimais, inclua no `app.module.ts`:

```
import { LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
...
@NgModule({
...
  providers: [
  ...
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'pt-BR' }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

O plugin [ion-currencymask](https://github.com/Pluritech/ion-currencymask) me ajudou bastante para este fim que necessita.